# The correct way to design data loading and object creation

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I'm working on an app for iphone where I load a JSON from a php server, parse it with a library and create an object with this data. My code works fine but the way I do it seems wrong to me:

A viewController shows to the user a loading view. Meanwhile the ViewController makes the get request and receive the data.
The VC parse the response and get a dictionary
The dictionary is send to a "creator class" who returns a object created from the dictionary

I do two times this operation but I think it's a bad design:

Should a View Controller do a http request? Don't shoud be a "objectLoader"? The main method of creation class makes a big bunch of if/else spaghettis, like:

```
for(NSString key in dictionary){
    if(key isEqualToString "a key"){
         perform action
    }
    else if(key isEqualToString "an other key"){
         perform action
    }
    ....
}
```

Any idea to solve that? I was thinking about make a dictionary of keys/selectors to solve it and do something like:

```
 for(NSString key in dictionary){
    [self performSelector:[selectors getObjectForKey:key]]
}
```

But I don't know if I can reference a selector in a dictionary...

Finally the other option that comes to me is send the parsed dictionary to the object with a class method like: `[ClassName createObjectWithDictionary:parsedDictionary]`. That's a good way to do it?

I know the question is a little ambiguous but I'm a little lost in what Design patterns I should apply and who is responsible of what in this story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way is to use MVC pattern and have model with data that has methods to push and remove some data inside it and a list of delegates (derived from UIViewController) which are notified in case of changed model data.
Controller (not UIViewController) is something that initiates fetching data from server and handles results.
And all of UIViewControllers handles data changes and user interaction.
For now, write some RequestController (singletone or not, doesn't matter) that handles request routines and stores all necessary data to trigger events in controller. 
You can use blocks or NSNotificationCenter to handle request's completion.
After getting necessary data through RequestController from request, your Controller can create necessary parsers and push parsed data into model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm sorry because I don't know if I understand well your method. The UIViewController should create the controller? Should I have a controller for every request type I have? So the controller should be the man in the middle between the UIViewController and the model for object loading from my server? The controller should process the received data? SOrry for my questions, I'm trying to learn the best way to design my software.

Comment: "The UIViewController should create the controller?" - not required, it can be created by app delegate and set from viewController. "Should I have a controller for every request type I have" - no, my suggestion is to have controllers for exact roles. One - for loading common data, one for loading resources and so on. "So the controller should be the man in the middle between the UIViewController and the model for object loading from my server?" - yes, smth like that. "The controller should process the received data?" - it depends, if you have controller for data requests, you can move

Comment: data processing to corresponding viewController, but if you have controller for doing particular data requests, it can parse and jsut notify viewController about new data.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would NOT let the ViewController do the HTTP request. I always write service classes in my apps, that do the low level stuff and inform the caller (e.g. a view controller) via delegation on any received result.

So the control flow in that case is:
-> ViewController locks screen with loading message 
-> calls service with itself as delegate - the service does the work and receives the answer -> the answer is processed and the result passed to the delegate 
-> the ViewController takes the response, removes the loading message and does whatever is necessary with the response.

Concerning your second question: yes, it is possible to dynamically chose a selector out of a dictionary - e.g. by storing the selector's name in the dictionary and then use

```
SEL selector = selectorFromString(@"doWork");
```

to create the right selector to call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I have a doubt, your service should be like a factory pattern that depending on something like url parse and create and return the object. Or the dictionary process should be something of the model class? My problem is that in the dictionary creation implies a lot of classes and the service will grow too much....